# Where can `const` qualified types occur in C99 programs

Tags: c, c99

**TL;DR** Where can `const` appear in a C99 program and not be ignored? Or conversely: where in a C99 program does `const` add non-trivial constraints?

---

My understanding is that the `const` qualifier is only useful in a handful of the places where qualified types are allowed. "Useful" is used in a semantic sense here, meaning "adding non-trivial constraints". My list of places where `const` is useful includes:

- attached to pointer and array types to describe the mutability of the pointed / element type. E.g. `int const *`
- describing the mutability of some variable declaration (either as a function argument, or a local variable). E.g. `int const x = 1`
- describe the mutability of some field in a `struct`/`union`. E.g. `struct Foo { int baz; int const quux; }`
- in `typedef`'s, when those are used in one of the cases above
- ???

I'm having a tough time getting an exhaustive list of these. I've skimmed over the C99 spec, but that is hardly light reading. :)

Help much appreciated!

## Edit

Here are some cases where AFAICT `const` is not "useful":

- any return value (rvalues cannot be mutated). E.g. `const int foo() { return 2; }`
- any cast (still rvalues...). E.g. `(int const) bar()`
- `sizeof` (the alignment and size of qualified/unqualified types is the same). E.g. `sizeof(const int)`

Comment: @Alec: Well, in that case everything can be folded into a single point: `const` is a type-qualifier and it is used to qualify types in *declarations*. You seem to be trying to build a *finer* classification. And if so, I don't see why `struct` is a separate case and `void foo(const int i)` isn't.

Comment: @AnT But that isn't strictly true - the `const` in `(int const *) ptr` is not a declaration, yet it _is_ useful.

Comment: @AnT I'm trying to separate language constructs. `void foo(const int i)` is a function with a constant argument, `struct Foo { int baz; int const quux; }` is a `struct` with a constant field. They seem different enough to me - but I could well be wrong. How are they the same?

Comment: @Alec: True. A more correct thing to say would be: type-qualifiers are used in type-names. That would make a single bullet. If you want a finer classification, then you can split type-name-related contexts into: declarations, casts, compound literals, generics, `sizeof`, `_Atomic`, `_Alignas`, `_Alignof`. But I don't see the point.

Comment: @AnT Where did you pull that list from - it looks like a handy partitioning of the problem! Also, where in compound literals, `sizeof` and `_Atomic` is `const` useful? Regarding the point of all this: I'm consuming AST information from Clang and I'd prefer to figure out upfront on which nodes there is _useful_ `const` information to extract.

Comment: @AnT Also, "type-qualifiers are used in type-names" is interesting, but I'm interested in when type-qualifiers are __useful__ in type-names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the language grammar *type-qualifier* can appear as part of *type-name*. If you look through the language grammar for *type-name* you'll find all contexts in which it can be used. That would be: declarations, casts, compound literals, generics, `sizeof`, `_Atomic`, `_Alignas`, `_Alignof`.

- It is safe to say that in the context of the last four - `sizeof`, `_Atomic`, `_Alignas`, `_Alignof` - `const` makes no difference at any level of indirection.
- `_Generic` still appears to be underspecified, but it is probably safe to assume that top-level `const` makes no difference there. At deeper levels of indirection `const` matters in `_Generic`.
- As for the others, the governing rule would be: top-level `const` is only meaningful with *lvalues*. It makes no difference when applied to *rvalues*. Which means that there's no point in applying top-level const-qualifications to function return types or to target types in casts.

  Qualifiers used at deeper levels of indirection, obviously, matter.

  Note that compound literals are lvalues, meaning that top-level `const` in compound literals matters

  ```
  int *p = (const struct { int a[10]; }) { 0 }.a; // Error: discards `const`
  ```
- Some curious examples remain, e.g.

  ```
  const struct S { int a[10]; } foo(void)
  {
    return (struct S) { 0 };
  }

  int main()
  {
    int *p = foo().a;
  }
  ```

  It compiles in GCC, but, if I'm not mistaken, the behavior is undefined anyway.

Comment: Right. Compound literals _can_ be lvalues, so `const` _can_ constrain something in that case. Thanks for the detailed answer! By the way, do you have a link to the grammar you were searching through?

Comment: @Alec: I just used a draft of C11 standard.

Comment: @Alec: "Can be"? AFAIK, compound literals are *always* lvalues.

Comment: I'm not sure but discard const in casting could be wrong for pointer, if you are casting something like `int a = 42; int const *i = &a; void const *p = i; i = (int const *)p;` if you do not add const in your rvalue compiler warning you "warning: cast from 'const void *' to 'int *' drops const qualifier".

Comment: Sorry. Yes. I meant that they are not always used as rvalues.

Comment: @Stargateur I think the discussion is only about top-level `const` in casts. There is no question that `const` in pointer types (in casts or outside) is not useful.